# Eliminar varias columnas que tienen una característica común

Tags: r, dataframe

Necesito eliminar varias filas de un data frame con 6 columnas, todas las filas que quiero eliminar son iguales y en 4 de esas columnas esas filas tienen como valor `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Pondré un ejemplo hipotético. En donde el `df` tiene 6 columnas.

```
df
   a    b    d    e    f    g
1  6   TE NULL NULL NULL    3
2  5 CAFE    A NULL NULL NULL
3  1   TE    A    1 NULL NULL
4  4 CAFE NULL NULL    X NULL
5  1 CAFE    A NULL NULL NULL
6  8   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
7  8   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
8  8   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
9  6 CAFE NULL NULL NULL NULL
10 5   TE NULL    1 NULL    3
11 1   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
12 4   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
13 9   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
14 7 CAFE    A    1 NULL NULL
15 5   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
16 6   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
17 5   TE NULL NULL    X    3
18 5   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
19 7   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
20 2   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
21 7   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
22 4 CAFE    A NULL    X    3
23 4   TE NULL NULL NULL    3
24 5   TE    A NULL NULL NULL
25 2   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
26 4   TE NULL NULL NULL NULL
27 9   TE NULL NULL    X    3
28 1   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
29 6 CAFE NULL NULL NULL    3
30 5   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
```

Y si deseas eliminar las filas en donde, las 4 columnas tienen como valor NULL, con `R` base lo haces así:

```
df<-df[!(df$d=="NULL" & df$e=="NULL" & df$f=="NULL" & df$g=="NULL"),]
```

A lo que te resultaría:

```
> df
   a    b    d    e    f    g
1  6   TE NULL NULL NULL    3
2  5 CAFE    A NULL NULL NULL
3  1   TE    A    1 NULL NULL
4  4 CAFE NULL NULL    X NULL
5  1 CAFE    A NULL NULL NULL
8  8   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
10 5   TE NULL    1 NULL    3
12 4   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
14 7 CAFE    A    1 NULL NULL
16 6   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
17 5   TE NULL NULL    X    3
20 2   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
21 7   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
22 4 CAFE    A NULL    X    3
23 4   TE NULL NULL NULL    3
24 5   TE    A NULL NULL NULL
27 9   TE NULL NULL    X    3
28 1   TE NULL NULL    X NULL
29 6 CAFE NULL NULL NULL    3
30 5   TE NULL    1 NULL NULL
```

En donde se ha eliminado las 4 columnas en donde se tenía `NULL` en todas.

Espero, haber ayudado.